# What is JOYINFOEX::dwButtonNumber?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm currently trying to write a virtual joystick using PPJoy. In order to do this, I have to create a DLL that exports joyGetCapsA() and joyGetPosEx() which should work like their Windows API counterparts. So I need to know how they work, and partially I don't.

My particular problem is with joyGetPosEx() which writes information about the joystick's current state into a JOYINFOEX object. I understand most of the JOYINFOEX struct (it is documented in the MSDN, after all), but there's this:

**dwButtonNumber**
Current button number that is pressed. (source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

What is this? The total number of buttons currently pressed?

(It also doesn't work, somewhere (outside my DLL) a SIGFPE is triggered. But that's a different problem.)

Thanks,

Mr. Wonko

Answer (score 1):

I would think this poorly described member is the total number of joystick buttons currently being pressed. Although the documentation doesn't exactly say, I wouldn't be surprised if this requires the `JOY_RETURNBUTTONS` flag to be set in order to return it.

Comment: That's my guess, too... I just don't like guessing. Well, guessing is fine, but knowing is better. Anyway I just decided I'd give the other PPJoy DLL variant a try, the callback version. It seems to be both easier and more capable (allowing for up to 8 instead of 6 axes).

Comment: I couldn't get the Callback version to work either, though I did get further than on the last try, but I found a working example application for doing it from within a program, which is fine by me since I'll need a setup utility anyway, might as well keep that running, XBCD-style.